# Problem with method. Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'book' is a 'let' constant

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, swiftui

I am very new to SwiftUI (few days of studying), and when learning basics, I've encountered a problem that I can't seem to figure out.

I would like to have a method (changeBookRead()) that will toggle book variable "read" when button is clicked.
The problem is, I think, that the book is structs instance inside of an array, but I am not sure if that's correct.

I will appreciate if you can help me with solution.

**Book struct with changeBookRead() method**

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var title = String()
@State private var author = String()
@State private var isRead = false;
@State private var books = [Book]()
@State private var showingAlert = false

func toggleRead () {
    isRead.toggle()
}

struct Book {
    let ID = UUID()
    
    let bookTitle: String
    let bookAuthor: String
    @State var read: Bool
    
    // Function that changes read status of specific book instance
    mutating func changeBookRead () {
        read.toggle()
        print(read)
    }
}

func addToBooks () {
    let book = Book(bookTitle: title, bookAuthor: author, read: isRead)
    books.append(book)
}
```

**Body section - last button in the ForEach loop is the one I want to use.**

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            TextField("Book title", text: $title)
                .padding()
            TextField("Book author", text: $author)
                .padding()
            Group{
                Toggle(isOn: $isRead) {
                    Text("Did I read it...?")
                    
                }
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: .orange))
                .padding()
                .frame(minWidth: 100)
                .animation(.default, value:isRead)
                Button("Add book") {
                    addToBooks()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .tint(.orange)
                
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("My Books")
            ForEach(books, id: \.ID) { book in
                VStack {
                    Text("Book Title: \(book.bookTitle)")
                    Text("Book Author: \(book.bookAuthor)")
                    Button("Remove book", role: .destructive) {
                        showingAlert.toggle()
                    }
                    .alert("Do you want to remove this book?", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                        Button("Remove", role: .destructive) {
                            books.removeAll(where: { $0.ID == book.ID})
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    Button(book.read ? "Is Read" : "Want to read") {
                        book.changeBookRead()
                    }
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can only use a @State property wrapper inside a View

Comment: Rather unrelated but basically do not put the model into the view. That's a very bad practice.

Comment: @vadian of course, all suggestions are welcome, because my knowledge is terrible right now. Which model are you speaking about?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would like the variable to be separate in each Struc instancet, so that each book that is displayed has its own Read status. Is it doable that way?

Comment: Each instance of a struct is separate so every property of the struct is separate to that instance. Anyway, you need to remove @State from the Book property `read`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ah, right, I know what you mean. Still the problem persists, if I keep the variable read without State, I still get an error "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'book' is a 'let' constant"

Comment: Use a view model, a class conforming to `ObservableObject` and do the model related work there. The `View` is only for displaying data.

Comment: Please study [Apple’s SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) & [Stanford’s CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/).